# TypeOrm: handle .save() that is called twice at the exact same time in an express API context

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I have a `getUser` function that return a `User` entity after being saved into the database for caching reasons. Here is the **pseudo-code** for it:

```js
export const getUser = async (userId: string): Promise<User> => {
  if (userStoredInDatabase) return userStoredInDatabase // <- pseudo code 
   
  // ...if no user stored -> fetch external services to get user name, avatar, ...
  const user = new User()
  user.id = userId // <- PRIMARY KEY
  // ...add data to the user

  return getManager().save(user)
}
```

I use this function in 2 distinct routes of a simple expressjs API:

```js
app.get('/users/:userId/profile', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await getUser(req.params.userId)
  // ...
})
app.get('/users/:userId/profile-small', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await getUser(req.params.userId)
  // ...
})
```

So far so good until I came to the problem that my frontend need to fetch `/users/:userId/profile` and `/users/:userId/profile-small` at the exact same time to show the 2 profiles. If the user is not yet cached in the database, the `.save(user)` will be called twice almost at the same time and I will respond for one of the 2 with an error due to an invalid sql insertion as the given `user.id` already exists.

I know I could just delay one of the request to make it work good enough but I'm not in the favor of this hack.

Do you have any idea how to concurrently `.save()` a `User` even if it is called at the same time from 2 different contexts so that TypeOrm knows for one of the 2 calls that `user.id` already exist and therefore do an `update` instead of an `insert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using delay will not solve the prolm since the user can open 3 tabs at the same time. Concurency has to be handled.

Catch if there is a primary key violation (Someone already has stored the user between the get user and persist user code block)

Here is an example:

```js
export const getUser = async (userId: string): Promise<User> => {
  try {

    if (userStoredInDatabase) return userStoredInDatabase // <- pseudo code 
   
    // ...if no user stored -> fetch external services to get user name, avatar, ...
    const user = new User()
    user.id = userId // <- PRIMARY KEY
    // ...add data to the user

    return getManager().save(user)
  } catch (e) {
    const isDuplicatePrimaryKey = //identify it is a duplicate key based on e prop,this may differ depending on the SQL Engine that you use. Debugging will help
    if (isDuplicatePrimaryKey) {
      return await //load user from db
    }
    throw e; // since e is not a duplicate primary key, the issue is somewhere else
  }
}
```

Comment: Mmmh not bad at all as the `catch` will be evaluated once only if the function is called more than once at the same time and there was no user stored before. Should solve my problem. Will wait a bit before validating your answer to see if there is other techniques.